# ActiveMQ Artemis in Docker shows empty screen

Tags: activemq-artemis, artemiscloud

## Short version

When I run ActiveMQ Artemis in docker I see this basically empty screen:

[image: empty screen]

That doesn't look right... I was expecting this, like I get when using the zip file:

[image: normal-looking activemq screen]

Regardless of whether I use docker or the zip file, it doesn't matter what username or password I enter, I just get logged in regardless, which is a little concerning...

What am I doing wrong?

## Longer Version

I'm attempting a "Hello World" style installation of ActiveMQ. It sounds like ActiveMQ Artemis is what I should be using. We'll be using this on Kubernetes, so I found and have followed https://artemiscloud.io/. There is a [Quickly deploy a basic Container image that runs the broker](https://artemiscloud.io/blog/deploybasicimage/) right there on the front page. It suggests:

```
docker run -e AMQ_USER=admin -e AMQ_PASSWORD=admin -p80:8161 --name artemis quay.io/artemiscloud/activemq-artemis-broker:dev.latest
```

I changed the port to `-p8161:8161` and run it using Docker for Windows. Visiting http://localhost:8161/console/ shows me the first screenshot above.

If I instead download from https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/download/ and follow https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/using-server.html I get the second screenshot.

Regardless of whether I use docker or the zip file, it doesn't matter what username or password I enter, I just get logged in regardless.

## Full docker console log

```
» docker run -e AMQ_USER=admin -e AMQ_PASSWORD=admin -p8161:8161 --name artemis quay.io/artemiscloud/activemq-artemis-broker:latest
Creating Broker with args --user XXXXX --password XXXXX --role admin --name broker --allow-anonymous --http-host 172.17.0.3 --host 172.17.0.3   --force
Creating ActiveMQ Artemis instance at: /home/jboss/broker

Auto tuning journal ...
done! Your system can make 1.44 writes per millisecond, your journal-buffer-timeout will be 696000

You can now start the broker by executing:  

   "/home/jboss/broker/bin/artemis" run

Or you can run the broker in the background using:

   "/home/jboss/broker/bin/artemis-service" start

Running Broker
     _        _               _
    / \  ____| |_  ___ __  __(_) _____
   / _ \|  _ \ __|/ _ \  \/  | |/  __/
  / ___ \ | \/ |_/  __/ |\/| | |\___ \
 /_/   \_\|   \__\____|_|  |_|_|/___ /
 Apache ActiveMQ Artemis 2.17.0


2021-05-27 21:23:44,556 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.integration.bootstrap] AMQ101000: Starting ActiveMQ Artemis Server
2021-05-27 21:23:44,605 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221000: live Message Broker is starting with configuration Broker Configuration (clustered=false,journalDirectory=data/journal,bindingsDirectory=data/bindings,largeMessagesDirectory=data/large-messages,pagingDirectory=data/paging)
2021-05-27 21:23:44,650 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221012: Using AIO Journal
2021-05-27 21:23:44,694 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221057: Global Max Size is being adjusted to 1/2 of the JVM max size (-Xmx). being defined as 1,073,741,824
2021-05-27 21:23:44,712 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221043: Protocol module found: [artemis-server]. Adding protocol support for: CORE
2021-05-27 21:23:44,712 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221043: Protocol module found: [artemis-amqp-protocol]. Adding protocol support for: AMQP
2021-05-27 21:23:44,713 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221043: Protocol module found: [artemis-hornetq-protocol]. Adding protocol support for: HORNETQ
2021-05-27 21:23:44,713 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221043: Protocol module found: [artemis-mqtt-protocol]. Adding protocol support for: MQTT
2021-05-27 21:23:44,713 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221043: Protocol module found: [artemis-openwire-protocol]. Adding protocol support for: OPENWIRE
2021-05-27 21:23:44,714 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221043: Protocol module found: [artemis-stomp-protocol]. Adding protocol support for: STOMP
2021-05-27 21:23:44,759 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221034: Waiting indefinitely to obtain live lock
2021-05-27 21:23:44,760 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221035: Live Server Obtained live lock
2021-05-27 21:23:44,832 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221080: Deploying address DLQ supporting [ANYCAST]
2021-05-27 21:23:44,839 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221003: Deploying ANYCAST queue DLQ on address DLQ
2021-05-27 21:23:44,880 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221080: Deploying address ExpiryQueue supporting [ANYCAST]
2021-05-27 21:23:44,882 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221003: Deploying ANYCAST queue ExpiryQueue on address ExpiryQueue
2021-05-27 21:23:45,148 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221020: Started EPOLL Acceptor at 172.17.0.3:61616 for protocols [CORE,MQTT,AMQP,STOMP,HORNETQ,OPENWIRE]
2021-05-27 21:23:45,152 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221020: Started EPOLL Acceptor at 172.17.0.3:5445 for protocols [HORNETQ,STOMP]
2021-05-27 21:23:45,155 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221020: Started EPOLL Acceptor at 172.17.0.3:5672 for protocols [AMQP]
2021-05-27 21:23:45,158 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221020: Started EPOLL Acceptor at 172.17.0.3:1883 for protocols [MQTT]
2021-05-27 21:23:45,162 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221020: Started EPOLL Acceptor at 172.17.0.3:61613 for protocols [STOMP]
2021-05-27 21:23:45,167 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221007: Server is now live
2021-05-27 21:23:45,168 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ221001: Apache ActiveMQ Artemis Message Broker version 2.17.0 [broker, nodeID=d1043ae4-bf31-11eb-8c49-0242ac110003] 
2021-05-27 21:23:45,379 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.hawtio.branding.PluginContextListener] Initialized activemq-branding plugin
2021-05-27 21:23:45,413 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.hawtio.plugin.PluginContextListener] Initialized artemis-plugin plugin
2021-05-27 21:23:45,625 INFO  [io.hawt.HawtioContextListener] Initialising hawtio services
2021-05-27 21:23:45,636 INFO  [io.hawt.system.ConfigManager] Configuration will be discovered via system properties
2021-05-27 21:23:45,638 INFO  [io.hawt.jmx.JmxTreeWatcher] Welcome to Hawtio 2.11.0
2021-05-27 21:23:45,643 INFO  [io.hawt.web.auth.AuthenticationConfiguration] Starting hawtio authentication filter, JAAS realm: "activemq" authorized role(s): "admin" role principal classes: "org.apache.activemq.artemis.spi.core.security.jaas.RolePrincipal"
2021-05-27 21:23:45,656 INFO  [io.hawt.web.proxy.ProxyServlet] Proxy servlet is disabled
2021-05-27 21:23:45,660 INFO  [io.hawt.web.servlets.JolokiaConfiguredAgentServlet] Jolokia overridden property: [key=policyLocation, value=file:/home/jboss/broker/etc/jolokia-access.xml]
2021-05-27 21:23:45,727 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis] AMQ241001: HTTP Server started at http://172.17.0.3:8161
2021-05-27 21:23:45,727 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis] AMQ241002: Artemis Jolokia REST API available at http://172.17.0.3:8161/console/jolokia
2021-05-27 21:23:45,728 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis] AMQ241004: Artemis Console available at http://172.17.0.3:8161/console
2021-05-27 21:23:54,289 INFO  [io.hawt.web.auth.LoginServlet] Hawtio login is using 1800 sec. HttpSession timeout
2021-05-27 21:23:54,968 INFO  [io.hawt.web.auth.keycloak.KeycloakServlet] Keycloak integration is disabled
2021-05-27 21:24:00,270 INFO  [io.hawt.web.auth.LoginServlet] Logging in user: admin
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding the environment variable -e AMQ_EXTRA_ARGS="--http-host 0.0.0.0 --relax-jolokia" in docker run command brings up the admin console and shows up the expected admin content.

Comment: I just tried to log in that seems to work! (I'm no longer investigating this). Can somebody else also confirm that this actually works for real traffic too?

Answer (score 3):

The ArtemisCloud container image for [ActiveMQ Artemis](https://github.com/artemiscloud/activemq-artemis-broker-image) is designed to run inside a container so the container IP address should be used to access to the console or to other resources.

The container IP address can be obtained by using the command `docker inspect` or by reading the container log, ie:

```
[org.apache.activemq.artemis] AMQ241004: Artemis Console available at http://172.17.0.3:8161/console
```

Comment: Even though I'm sure you're right, that really sucks. Because on "Docker for Windows", the containers are run inside a wsl2 container, and I cannot access port 8161 on 172.17.0.3 from either the windows environment or from other wsl2 containers. I can however access port 8161 from localhost and from the Windows hosts's IP address. Is there any way to get ActiveMQ Artemis to work regardless of what IP address I access it as?

Comment: I'm guessing it is because [launch.sh line 16](https://github.com/artemiscloud/activemq-artemis-broker-image/blob/8c162c298dd229d2f702fbeefc761a9b5f202ad5/modules/activemq-artemis-install/added/launch.sh#L16) has `... --http-host $BROKER_IP ...` and a previous line has: `export BROKER_IP=\`hostname -I | cut -f 1 -d ' '\``  :-(

Comment: I've created [issue #14 for activemq-artemis-broker-image](https://github.com/artemiscloud/activemq-artemis-broker-image/issues/14)