# ActiveMQ Artemis web console not showing

Tags: activemq-artemis

I am running ActiveMQ Artemis in a Kubernetes Pod with access via an Ingress. I get the web console showing but with no GUI:

I have disabled `jolokia-access.xml`, but I think the `artemis.profile` is not picking up my changes.

[image]

Could anyone help with this?

Comment: For future reference you should be tagging questions for ActiveMQ Artemis with `activemq-artemis`. You should **not** use the tag `artemis` as that is for a different, unrelated piece of software.

Comment: Ok Justin..will do

Comment: Are you still experiencing this problem?

Comment: No Justin... I used - - relax jolika in the broker create and set host bind to 0.0.0.0 in bootstrap

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is the configuration of your `etc/jolokia-access.xml`. The `allow-origin` should match where you've bound the web console, e.g.:

```xml
<restrict>
    <cors>
        <allow-origin>*://yourIPorHostname</allow-origin>
        <strict-checking/>
    </cors>
</restrict>
```

You can also essentially disable the CORS check by specifying `*://*`, e.g.:

```xml
<restrict>
    <cors>
        <allow-origin>*://*</allow-origin>
        <strict-checking/>
    </cors>
</restrict>
```

Comment: Hi Justin..I have already disabled CORS ..maybe my artemis.profile is not pointing to the correct jolokia-access.xml

Comment: That's an important detail you should add to the original question.

Comment: Justin - how can I get the artemis to look at my custom artemis.profile ? Can I pass this to the artemis run also ? That must be the problem as artemis.profile is showing location of jolokia-access.xml

Comment: Hi Justin - is there some way to run the broker with a custom profile.artemis (this will point to jolakia-access.xml)

Answer (score 5):

Run you docker with `AMQ_EXTRA_ARGS: "--host 0.0.0.0 --http-host 0.0.0.0 --relax-jolokia"`.

So you do not need persistence into the container.

Resulting file:

```
    <cors>
        <!-- Allow cross origin access from 0.0.0.0 ... -->
        <allow-origin>*://0.0.0.0*</allow-origin>


        <!-- Options from this point on are auto-generated by Create.java from the Artemis CLI -->
        <!-- option relax-jolokia used, so strict-checking will be removed here -->
    </cors>
```

Answer (score 0):

I also had same issue when using docker image. I fixed the issue by adding `-e AMQ_EXTRA_ARGS="--http-host 0.0.0.0 --relax-jolokia"`  to the `docker run` command.

Adding reference from stackoverflow.
[ActiveMQ Artemis in Docker shows empty screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67730226/activemq-artemis-in-docker-shows-empty-screen)